# Make specific Chrome profile the default profile

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I use Google Chrome on Ubuntu. I have two profiles: a personal one, and a work profile. Only the personal one is sync'ed to a Google account; the work profile is not synchronized as my work email address is not associated with Google.

I currently have my personal profile as default, and need to have my work profile ("Profile 1") as default instead. How can I do that?

I have searched for similar questions but the answers are no good, as they mostly say "change your shortcut icons to use google-chrome --profile='Profile 1'". This doesn't work as it still runs with "Default" profile when I click on a link in an application. What I really need is to switch the profiles to have "Default" as my work profile and "Profile 1" as my personal profile.

Comment: Have you tried simply switching the contents of the two user profile directories?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, that seems to have done the job! Thanks!